422 (Unprocessable Content) react native laravel
I'm currently working on a project involving uploading PDF files using React Native for the frontend and Laravel for the backend. However, I'm encountering an issue where the file upload is failing, and I'm receiving a 422 status code along with an AxiosError message indicating a bad request. Here's the error message I'm seeing: "Error uploading file: AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 422', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'...". Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue? Have you encountered similar problems before, and if so, how did you resolve them? Additionally, any suggestions on where I should look for more detailed error messages or logs, especially on the server side?
React native code
import React, { useState,useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthProvider';
import axiosConfig from '../helpers/axiosConfig';


const UploadPDFScreen = () => {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const pickDocument = async () => {
    try {
      const document = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        type: 'application/pdf',
      });
      
      const selectedFileName = document.assets[0].name; // Extract the file name
      setSelectedFile({ ...document, name: selectedFileName }); // Set the file name along with other properties
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error picking document: ', error);
    }
  };
  

  const uploadFile = async () => {

    if (!selectedFile) {
      console.error('No file selected');
      return;
    }

    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('pdf_file', selectedFile); // Append the file directly

      
            // Set authentication headers
       axiosConfig.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + user.token;


      const response = await axiosConfig.post('/upload-pdf', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });

      console.log('Upload success:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Select PDF File" onPress={pickDocument} />
      <Button title="Upload File" onPress={uploadFile} disabled={!selectedFile} />
      {selectedFile && (
        <View>
          <Text>Selected PDF: {selectedFile.name}</Text>
          {/* Further operations with the selected PDF */}
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default UploadPDFScreen;











Laravel app api
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class FileUploadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the upload of a PDF file.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function uploadPdf(Request $request)
    {
        // Define the validation rules
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'pdf_file' => 'required|file|mimes:pdf|max:10240', // max size 10MB
        ]);

        // Check if the validation fails
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }

        // Retrieve the validated file
        $file = $request->file('pdf_file');

        // Store the file in the specified directory
        $filePath = $file->store('public/pdfs');

        // Return a successful response with the file path
        return response()->json([
            'file_path' => Storage::url($filePath),
            'message' => 'File uploaded successfully',
        ], 201);
    }
}




Usually 422 status code happen when the validation failed. Did you check if there's a response content ?
